# Is there a rest call to list all the running applications in spark standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any rest call to list all the running applications on spark running in standalone mode?

I could find rest calls to submit application but not get all running applications !

UPDATED -
If we do not know the running application port and the history server is not enabled too than is there a way to get all running applications with just spark master and rest port details ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented API to get the status as json.

Just append `/json` to the spark standalone master UI URL.
This gives the UI representation in json.
The `activeapps` key has all the running applications.

Comment: Thank you! This should definitely be in the docs.

Comment: yes, this gives just UI json version, is there any way we can see these rest api, I am not able to find these with master in my standalone cluster https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST Api from Spark. Documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Here's an example:

```
http://localhost:4040/api/v1?status=running
```

Note:  For the history server, they would typically be accessible at `http://localhost:18080/api/v1` and for a running application, at `http://localhost:4040/api/v1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but If we do not know the running application port and the history server is not enabled too than is there a way to get all running applications with just spark master and rest port details ? 
I have modified the question too for being more specific.